# View more button inside a foreach loop only working for first item

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am looping through items on a foreach loop and every item comes with a "view more" tag. When I click it it should collapse and show more information about that item. My problem is that it is only collapsing for the first item on the loop. How do I make it work for every item that is returned?

```
 @{
                foreach (var news in Model)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="single-item  wow fadeInUp animated animated animated animated">
                            <div class="img-box">
                                <div class="img-holder">
                                    <figure><a href="#"><img src="@news.file.Url" alt=""></a></figure>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news-content">
                                <h4><a href="#">@news.Header</a></h4>

                                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                                    @news.Description
                                </div>

                                <div class="show-more">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" data-parent="collapseExample" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
```

This is my loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are rendering multiples elements with the **same** ID
Try this

```
var index = 1;
foreach(var news in Model){
   [...]

   <div class="collapse" id="collapse_@index">
        @news.Description
   </div>
   <div class="show-more">
       <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_@index" data-parent="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_@index">Read More</a>
   </div>                         

   index++;

   [...]
}
```

This way it will never repeat an ID element